# Xamarin Back Button on Android Requires Two Clicks To Navigate Backwards

Tags: android, xamarin, navigation

On Xamarin Android i have set in the App.cs the MainPage property to be a NavigationPage pointing to my MainPage.xaml page, which is a ContentPage. This navigates fine.

From a Command which executes from a Button in my MainPage.xaml I await a call to Navigation.PageAsync to go to my LoginPage.xaml, also a ContentPage. This works fine.

If i choose not to Login and wish to go back to the MainPage.xaml page from some unknown reason at the point where i was close to shipping it has decided that now it takes two clicks on the Android hardware back button to make this happen. This was not the case earlier in the day, it seems as if something has gone astray with Xamarin compilation as the only change i made was add some extra colors to a ResourceDictionary. This was working fine for months.

By the way, I have checked the NavigationStack, it is correct MainPage, and LoginPage (not two LoginPage instances). I also note RemovePage does not work anymore either, the point there being that if I do Login then i Remove the LoginPage so you don't come back to it from the following page.

In trying to find a cause I overrode OnBackButton inside the Android project and sure enough, the first click does not call it, only the second does. I have no idea how to fix this, my project was nearly ready to ship, and all of a sudden this. I've tried deleting the obj and bin folders and recompiling, Debug and Release, still the same. This is the case now on both emulator and physical devices.

Might anyone have an idea where to even begin looking how to fix this or better yet have a solution?

Comment: Could you share a mini demo? So that I can reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0):

So i finally figured it out, and it is not pretty. I was wrong about only adding colours, i had also moved from a page a Style that works on TargetType Entry into App.xaml. In theory this should NOT have made a jot of difference, it would be just be merged into all the pages ResourceDictionary as per any other resource placed at the App.xaml level. I have two pages that had the exact same Style for Entry so i consolidated them at the root.

But here is the kicker. The double back button press comes about from one setter property that is there and only when it is in the App.xaml. I had set CursorPosition to 0. This innocuous setter causes the backbutton not to fire, no exceptions are thrown, just that it has this effect. Hope this helps someone.

P.S I'd have moved to MAUI (indeed did a full port) but that has so many issues relating to Images and crashing and performance at this time it is not possible, so stuck with Xamarin for now, fying pan or fire.